Issue With Detecting Customer Details Using Web Pixel App Extension
I am currently developing a Web Pixel app extension. I have implemented the standard event "checkout_completed event", but I am experiencing inconsistent detection of this event, even when using the same environment and following the same steps to complete a purchase.
I have followed the implementation guide provided in the Shopify documentation:(https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/marketing/pixels/getting-started)
Here is an example of the code I am using:
import { register } from '@shopify/web-pixels-extension'

register(({ configuration, analytics, browser, settings, init }) => {
  analytics.subscribe('checkout_completed', async event => {
    console.log('checkout_completed:', event)
  })
})

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or knows of a solution, I would greatly appreciate your insights and guidance.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

To my knowledge, they've been issues of inconsistencies in the triggering of the checkout_completed event but all the others seems to work fine so for now i advice you make use of a combination of webhook subscription topics like CHECKOUTS_UPDATE, ORDERS_CREATE of the archive the same effect you intend to track with this web pixel event
